# C issues with extended ASCII characters

Tags: c, extended-ascii

I'm having trouble using variables in place of numeric values for characters in printf statements.

For example, `printf("%c", 201)` displays ╔ as I want it to but `printf("%c", var)` when `var` is of type `char` and `var=201` displays ♫.

Anyone have any information as to what's going on?

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead of `char`. On your system `char` must be `signed char` and assigning 201 to a variable of type `char` causes integer overflow.

Comment: Turns out I changed a variable from a `string` to an `int` and forgot to change the `scanf` format code. The whole problem was that I had mixed data types. My life.

Answer (score 0):

In fact if there is no `l` modifer the argument is converted to `unsigned char` so that's why you didn't observe any change when you changed your variable types, what you actually need is

```
printf("%lc", var);
```

but in

```
signed char var = 201;
```

overflow indeed occurs, so you should be careful.